# Restore one variable into redux from localStorage

Tags: reactjs, redux, local-storage

I'd like to persist a checkbox value, which is stored in the redux. I'm trying to restore it in reducer like this, but it doesn't appear to be working, always returning false. I don't want to sync the entire app's state, only a particular value, is there a simple solution for this?

```
const initialState = {
  isShowingDuplicates: localStorage.getItem('isShowingDuplicates') || false,
};
```

Comment: How and where are you setting 'isShowingDuplicates' to true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannnot get the value of a key from `localStorage` like this:

```
const initialState = {
  isShowingDuplicates: localStorage('isShowingDuplicates') || false,
};
```

The correct way to do is:

```
const initialState = {
  isShowingDuplicates: localStorage.getItem('isShowingDuplicates') || false,
};
```

Just be sure the you have already set the item into the `localStorage` like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('isShowingDuplicates', value);
```